# Error : VM Exception while processing transaction: revert

Tags: javascript, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

I am getting this error when I am transfering some tokens to the decentralized bank
Here is the code

Test.js:

```
 await decentralbank.stakeTokens(tokens("100"), {
    from: customer,
  });
```

DecentralBank.sol:

```
function stakeTokens(uint256 _amount) public {


    tether.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);

    // update staking balance
    stakingBalance[msg.sender] = stakingBalance[msg.sender] + _amount;

    // add user to stakers array *only* if they haven't staked already
    if (!hasStaked[msg.sender]) {
        stakers.push(msg.sender);
    }

    // update stakng status
    isStaking[msg.sender] = true;
    hasStaked[msg.sender] = true;
}
```

Tether.sol:

```
 function transferFrom(
    address _from,
    address _to,
    uint256 _value
) public  returns  (bool success) {
    require(_value <= balanceOf[_from]);
    require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);
    balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
    balanceOf[_to] += _value;
    allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
    emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you share all your smart contract code?

Answer (score 0):

By looking at that I guess you forgot to approve the token transfer before calling the `stakeTokens`.

```
await tether.approve(decentralbank.address, tokens("100"), {
  from: customer,
});

await decentralbank.stakeTokens(tokens("100"), {
  from: customer,
});
```

Also, one security note, you should call the `transferFrom` before all the state changes in the contract in order to avoid [re-entrancy attacks](https://solidity-by-example.org/hacks/re-entrancy), or you can just use this [library](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol).

Comment: I have approved the transferfrom function before using it and still its not working.